# Как создать такой заголовок на css?

Tags: html, css, photoshop

Как сделать такой заголовок на CSS? [image: Заколовок на CSS и HTML]

Нужно сделать рамку вокруг текста, как такое реализовать?
Такой заголовок выполнен в фотошопе с помощью кисти и обычного текста, шрифт и размеры шрифта мне известны. Я новичок в программировании.

Comment: опишите, пожалуйста (прямо в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit]), значение, которое вы вкладываете в слово «такой». во-первых, станет понятно, что вам нужно, во-вторых, вопрос (и ответ на него) будут проиндексированы поисковиками и смогут быть ползеными другим людям.

Comment: ... насколько мне видно: <h1>Отзывы</h1>  в css фон (думаю пипеткой справитесь), шрифт ( тут или у дизайнера спрашивай или подбором, отступы - тоже в зависимости от типа вёрстки ( в любых удобных тебе единицах)

Answer (score 2):

Какой вопрос - такой ответ

```css
body {background-color: #fff000}
.text {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<span class="text">Отзывы</span>
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!

Comment: @retevilin38, отметьте ответ, как правильный